# Is it okay to call heavy method in Select?

Tags: c#

I need to process several items from database and send processing status in JSON string back to caller. I wrote something like this (simplified):

```
string ProcessAll()
{
    return ConvertToJsonString(
        database.
        Get<XAccount>().
        Where(a => a.Enabled).
        Select(a => new
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Success = HeavyProcessing(a)
        }).
        ToArray());
}

bool HeavyProcessing(XAccount account)
{
    try
    {
        .... up to 10-20 HTTP requests here ......
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

`HeavyProcessing` is quite complex: internally it performs a lot of HTTP requests. Is it okay to call it in `Select`? If no, how can I elegantly redesign `ProcessAll`?

Another my idea was to create `IEnumerable<XAccountStatus> HeavyProcessAll(IEnumerable<XAccount> accounts)` method, and use `return yield` in it. Is it okay to use `yield` in heavy methods?

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't make much of a difference, because you call `ToArray` right after calling `Select` anyway, so you'd wait for all the items to be processed before you can proceed with further execution.

You can consider using parallel execution, using PLINQ, to perform these heavy operation for multiple items at the same time. `AsParallel` should make the trick:

```
string ProcessAll()
{
    return ConvertToJsonString(
        database.
        Get<XAccount>().
        Where(a => a.Enabled).
        AsParallel().
        Select(a => new
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Success = HeavyProcessing(a)
        }).
        ToArray());
}
```

Comment: So... architecturally it is okay to perform heavy data processing in LINQ? I was afraid LINQ is designed to transform collections, not to process data.

Comment: It's a bit opinion bases, but I think it's totally ok to use `Select` in the way you're using it right now.

Comment: @Denis as a generalization, most LINQ operations work like a foreach, so you can imagine the IL doing the same kind of work as if you wrote it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite a smart question to ask. I don't believe LINQ to Objects specifies the exact execution mode. It's not formally guaranteed that your selector will only be invoked once per item sequentially. If you only rely on formal guarantees made by the documentation you must assume that your "heavy" selector function might run multiple times or out of order.

Now clearly this is not what `Enumerable.Select` does. There is pretty much only one reasonable implementation possible:

```
foreach (var item in items) yield return selector(item);
```

I'm willing to rely on this fact in my projects and I recommend the same to everyone else.

Given that we now have (or assume) an executable model of how LINQ runs the query we can see that it is indeed safe to run a heavy selector with LINQ.

A possible complication would be lazy evaluation but you have excluded that possibility by materializing the sequence using `ToArray`.

Also consider the benefits in code quality that LINQ brings.

Writing a custom function using `yield return` as proposed in the question would essentially yield the same thing. If you inline your processing code into the code snippet given above (replace `selector` with it) you get what you propose. No need to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about Entity Framework? I'm pretty sure it will not work this way. EF would not know how to translate `HeavyProcessing` into SQL query and you'll get an exception in run time. So you'll have to get all `XAccount` items from the DB first, then apply `HeavyProcessing` on each of them.

Comment: It is pseudocode. If it crashes, I will put `AsEnumerable` after `Where`. I am talking about conception of calling `HeavyProcessing` directly in `Select`, is it okay?

Comment: uh, OK. Yes, I in this case I don't see a problem. As long as the code is readable and the intent is clear. However, I'd separate reading and writing data into different methods - this will make it more canonical.